# Quelle est la différence entre « avoir lieu » et « survenir » ?

Tags: sens, usage, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je sais qu'on utilise « avoir lieu » pour un accident, mais je voudrais l'utiliser pour une phrase du domaine de l'informatique. Puis-je dire « *Les systèmes d’exploitation empêchent les interblocages¹ de survenir* » ? ou dois-je plutôt utiliser *avoir lieu* ?

—
<sup>1. *deadlock*.</sup>

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre, qu'entends-tu par « les sources » ? De quelle impasse parles-tu ? Un peu plus de contexte ou d'explications nous aiderait surement à comprendre.

Comment: en englais on dit "operating systems manage sources to dead lock not happen"

Comment: Ok :-) je crois avoir pigé. Je remplace par « les OS empêchent les interblocages d'[…] ».

Comment: oui,c'est pas mal,merci

Comment: [_Une mouche survient, et des chevaux s'approche_](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/jean_de_la_fontaine/le_coche_et_la_mouche.html)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit suite aux commentaires*

> Les *systèmes d'exploitations gèrent* les *sources* pour que des *interblocages* ne se produisent pas.

N.B. :

- *systèmes d'exploitations* plutôt qu'OS que l'on emploie uniquement dans la sphère informatique.
   Un OS est, pour le commun des mortels un *Ouvrier Spécialisé*.
  On n'utilisera OS que pour une public d'informaticien.
- *gèrent* pour *manage*. Au sens strict, un OS n'empêche rien, c'est le programme qui s'en charge.
- les *sources* s'il s'agit du code contrôlé sinon je dirais plutôt les *ressources* s'il s'agit de l'ensemble des moyens mis à disposition.
- *interblocages* : on pourrait aussi laisser *deadlock* dans une traduction technique, car le terme n'y est pas toujours traduit.

Ici j'emploie plus facilement *se produire* synonyme de *à lieu* plutôt que *survienne*  :

- un blocage vient d'un code erroné que l'on aurait dû 'recetter'¹ et valider avant de mettre en exploitation, il en est le *produit*, le résultat d'un problème dans les *sources* (ou les *ressources*).
- alors qu'une panne ou un accident *à lieu* ou *survient* par une cause externe, sans qu'il y ait de faute commise par l'exploitant, elle *vient* de l'extérieur.
  —
  <sup>1.  'recetter' néologisme que l'on emploie dans l'administration pour faire une recette d'application (souvent développée par des sous-traitants) qui n'a rien à voir avec le reset anglophone. C'est-à-dire qu'une application en développement est mise en recette pour déboguer et valider les IHM (Interface Homme Machine) et les traitements, renvoyée pour corrections ou mise en production pour le public. C'est à entendre dans le sens de "réception/validation d'un code nouveau ou modifié" et non de recette de cuisine.</sup>

Ce choix est très subjectif.
Si l'on veut conserver l'idée d'*empêcher* :

> Les systèmes d'exploitations empêchent les interblocages d'avoir lieu,
>   
>  Les systèmes d'exploitations empêchent les interblocages de
>   survenir.

*Survenir* (qui arrive à l'improviste) marque le moment où le phénomène arrive
*avoir lieu* (arriver, se passer, se produire) indique aussi l'endroit et la période durant laquelle la gène est occasionnée.

Ils peuvent être pris pour synonymes s'il s'agit d'un accident, d'un impondérable.

Pour traduire la phrase anglaise du commentaire (*happen* : arriver, se passer, se produire) :

> Les systèmes d'exploitation gèrent les ressources pour que les
>   interblocages ... 
>   ... ne se produisent pas.
>   ... n'arrivent pas.
>   ... n'aient pas lieu
>   ... ne surviennent pas.

Comment: Euh *Recetter* !?

Comment: Je crois que c'est une francisation un peu inattendue de *to reset*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez oui, *recetter* est très employé dans le monde de la production industrielle.

Comment: Justification des votes négatifs ?

Comment: @cl-r: La phrase est incompréhensible (je [sais](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9426/stephane-gimenez?tab=answers) ce que c'est un OS) et elle suggère plein de termes qui peuvent induire l'OP en erreur car ils n'étaient pas l'objet de sa question. La différence entre « avoir lieu » et « survenir » n'est pas expliquée.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai entendu parlé de *blocage de verrous* il y a fort longtemps (une trentaine d'année), et ensuite deadlock sans traduction. Pour OS, voir les modifications.

Answer (score 2):

La version avec « avoir lieu » convient très bien sous cette forme :

> Les systèmes d'exploitation empêchent que des interblocages n'aient lieu.

*[Survenir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/survenir)* n'est pas complètement impossible, il contient l'idée d'un évènement brusque, inopiné, intempestif, imprévu, presque malicieux dans un procédé ou une affaire en cours. Si un procédé (comme l'exécution d'un programme dans ce cas) était plus clairement défini, *survenir* conviendrait très bien.